# Use javascript variable in Laravel PHP

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Hi i m  trying to develop a **students registration application**  with **Laravel**

a student could be register in **many classes** each class has a **name and level** so in registration page i want to show a cheackbox with Classes Name then when i click on a Classe the application show me in the same page a groupe of cheakbox with levels og the cheakes class for exemple if i click on English it shows me Beginin , intermediate ...

So in create.blade.php (register) i have

```
@foreach ($mat as $m)
{!!Form::label($m->matiere,$m->matiere.' :')!!}
<input type="radio" name="matiere" onclick="cli();" value={!!$m->matiere!!}>
@endforeach
```

And i create a Script to help with cli() function

```
function cli(){       
 classname=document.querySelector('input[name="matiere"]:checked').value;
alert(classname);}
```

my question is how could i get classnam value in PHP to show the levels of this class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be taking an odd approach to this.

In your controller, before you pass any variables to your view, you will want to organize your `classes` and the `levels` you want to return. If you have set up your model relationships then you could even do this:

`Controller`

```
public function index()
{
    $classes = MyClassModel::all();

    return view('create', [
        'mat' => $classes,
    ]);
}
```

`create.blade.php`

```
@foreach ($mat as $m)
    {!!Form::label($m->matiere,$m->matiere.' :')!!}
    <input type="radio" name="matiere" value={!!$m->matiere!!}>
    @foreach ($m->levels as $level)
        // output each level for that class
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

You can then use javascript to show or hide the different levels as appropriate. I would avoid any asynchronous javascript unless you have enough classes and/pr levels that it would cause loading issues.

Comment: i was thinking in that solution  thnk u so much

Answer (score 0):

when the browser send request to server for this page, php make all of your html and javascript code and send them to browser and your javascript code run on browser, so you can't use php and javascript at the same place (ex. on the server).